# routing not working in node.js and express.js API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to seperate route from node.js server to folder routes. But it is not working.

When I run the server, `console.log('hello from express')` not printed . Also the `res.send()` is not executed.

**routes/index.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/api/hello', (req, res) => {
  console.log({ express: 'Hello From Express' });

  res.send({ express: 'Hello From Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

and **server.js**

```js
var indexRoute=require('./routes/index.js');

app.use('/api/hello',indexRoute);
```

How can I solve the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what isn't working? what's the exact problem you're having?

Comment: when i run the server , console.log('hello from express') not printed . Also the res.send() not executed

Comment: Ok, you are confused I think. current you would have to type `/api/hello/api/hello` for your code to do anything.

Comment: The problem is that you've duplicated the path in the server.js and in the router file. Remove the routers path write `router.get('/', controller)`. This means that that controller path is routed from the parent path. In that case, the one defined in `/api/hello`. In you current code, access to: `/api/hello/api/hello` and should work. After my changes, you'll be able to access using `/api/hello`

Comment: Ok , this work.but is i hava another route .post('/api/world) what i hava to put router.get('',controller)

Comment: @RaslanDyab take a look at my answer, it shows multiple routes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code :

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log({ express: 'Hello From Express' });

  res.send({ express: 'Hello From Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

This code is about what to do when the use hits the route you specify in :

```js
app.use('/api/hello',indexRoute);
```

So your **route** should only deal with *after* the `/api/hello`

Lets look at an example:

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/hello', (req, res) => {
  res.send({ express: 'Hello From Express' });
});

router.get('/goodbye', (req, res) => {
  res.send({ express: 'Goodbye From Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

This **route handler** is now defined to handle `[URL]/hello` and `[URL]/goodbye`
So lets hook it up on the site to the url `[site]/greeting/`:

```js
app.use('/greeting', indexRoute);
```

Now on our site we have 2 routes `[site]/greeting/hello` and `[site]/greeting/goodbye`