# nodejs specific route not displaying sql query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, function, node-modules

I'm new to javascript and nodejs and i have a question

I have a code who i'm working in a simple api and i'm getting a lot of trouble to understand why this is happening

```
app.get('/api/list_all', (req, res) => {
    get_info(`SELECT * FROM users;`, function(result){
        res.json(result);
    });
});
```

I have this route to list all the users for me on screen for a local host mysql. The connection are working but when i type the route, returns me a blank screen with "[]" (empty list)

The console and the html page does not display any errors

But when i change the route for just "list_all" without the "api" part, it goes well. Like this:

```
app.get('/list_all', (req, res) => {
    get_info(`SELECT * FROM users;`, function(result){
        res.json(result);
    });
});
```

It returns me with the SQL response.

The question is: why is not working when i give the "api" on route?

The function "get_info":

```
function get_info(sql_data, callback){

    con.getConnection((error, conn) => {
        if (error) { throw error; }
        conn.query(
            sql_data,
            (error, resultado) => {
                conn.release();
                if (error) { throw error; }
                return callback(resultado)
            }
        )
    })
}
```

I was expecting the route "api/list_all" to return the SQL result with all users normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably importing wrong your code to your main server file

If the code shown above is in a different file from your **server** file you should add in the server.js the line `app.use('/api/list_all',imported_route);` and then change your code to

```
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    get_info(`SELECT * FROM users;`, function(result){
        res.json(result);
    });
   });
```

For more help refer to previous question [routing not working in node.js and express.js API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59418197/routing-not-working-in-node-js-and-express-js-api)

Comment: Soo, i was doing all in the same "main.js" script for a test but i saw the answer of the refer who you attached in and solved here the problem. Correct if i'm not mistaken but i have to create a new line of routes to get an adicional route like i have to create an "api" route to create the path "api/list_all". That's right? Thank you for our help, i'm new at nodejs.